# Is there any way to search for objects with the specific field in array of objects in google-cloud-firestore

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to query objects in array of objects with specific field in google cloud firestore,
I have collection structured like this :

```
...
{
    name: "shoes 1",
    amount:150,
    productors: [
        {
            id : "a001",
            name : "productor 1"
        },
        {
            id: "a002",
            name: "productor 2"
        }
        ...
    ]
    ...
}
{
    name: "shoes 2",
    amount:80,
    productors: [
        {
            id : "a002",
            name : "productor 2"
        },
        {
            id: "a001",
            name: "productor 1"
        }
        ...
    ]
    ...
}
...
```

and I would like to query this collection to get all docs that have in productors array, produtor with the id = e001.

I work in a nodejs environment, using firestore-admin-sdk

Comment: Which queries have you tried?  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries

Comment: Btw, the ">" is for quoting source material. ;)

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible with Cloud Firestore.  You can't query for properties of objects within an array.  You can only query an array for the entire value of one of its items (the full object).

For this query, you will need a separate field to query, perhaps array that contains only the id values you want to find.  You can use an [array-contains type query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership) for that.